# Redundancy issues in my Cordova iOS plugins

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I do not understand how Cordova (latest version 6.1) deals with plugins. I have the following project for my app:

```
myapp (only relevant folders and files shown)
+-config.xml
+-platforms
| +-ios
|   +-CordovaLib
|   +-MyApp
|     +-Plugins
|       +-com-myproj-myplugin
|         |-myplugin.h
|         |-myplugin.m
+-plugins
| +-com-myproj-myplugin
|   |-plugin.xml
|   +-src
|     +-ios
|       |-myplugin.h
|       |-myplugin.m
+-www
```

As you can see, this project has a plugin `myplugin` which resides in 2 directories:

- The root `plugins` folder - Here file `myapp\plugins\com-myproj-myplugin\src\ios\myplugin.m` does not contain any code implementation (just signatures and empty content in functions).
- The iOS application specific `Plugins` folder - Here file `myapp\platforms\ios\MyApp\Plugins\com.myproj.myplugin\myplugin.m` actually contains the implementation.

### Where is the redundancy?

I thought that the model was as follows:

1. I call `cordova build ios`.
2. Cordova will copy resources from `myapp\plugins\` into specific platform plugin folders in `myapp\platforms\...\Plugins\`

But turns out this is not the case. No copy is performed from the general `plugins` folder into platform specific `Plugins` folders.

**The plugin** Here is my `plugin.xml` for my plugin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" id="com.myproj.myplugin" version="0.1.0">
  <name>MyPlugin</name>
  <description>Just my plugin</description>
  <license>Me</license>
  <js-module src="www/myplugin.js" name="myplugin">
    <clobbers target="myplugin" />
  </js-module>

  <!-- ios -->
  <platform name="ios">
    <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
      <feature name="MyPlugin">
        <param name="ios-package" value="MyPlugin"/>
        <param name="onload" value="true"/>
      </feature>
    </config-file>

    <header-file src="src/ios/myplugin.h" />
    <source-file src="src/ios/myplugin.m" />
  </platform>
</plugin>
```

**My question** How am I supposed to develop the plugin in order to avoid this redundancy? Should the code be placed only in platform specific `Plugins` folder? But how about `plugin.xml` which is placed in the generic `plugins` folder?

Comment: You want to create your own plugin? You have to create the plugin folder with the classes and a plugin.xml file. The plugin.xml file is the one that tells cordova what to copy.

Comment: @jcesarmobile: Yes, however why isn't Cordova copying those files into platform specific plugin folders?

Comment: Do you have the plugin.xml file?

Comment: Yes I have for that specific plugin and it is specific the header and the source file.

Comment: If you install the plugin from the CLI and you have the plugin.xml then the files should be copied to the right place

Comment: Can you show your `plugin.xml`? My guess is that there is an error in there causing it not be be copied.

Comment: Just added in question